# responsive design is not working properly - too much is shown

Tags: html, css

I am wondering, why my responsive view shows more than it should.
[the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1kTg.png)
I have set

```
body {
width: 100%;
}
```

but there is still a scrollbar showing more on the right that it shouln't.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably you set fixed width in pixels (or other constant unit) somewhere. Anyway, it's difficult to help you without any source code.

Comment: You can also look at margins and paddings, which could be added on top of the 100% width

Answer (score 1):

on your page there is an element which is wider than 100% width.

a fix could be:

```css
body{
width: 100vw;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but better you identify the wider element and fix the size of that element